# For loop and 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I have a simple for loop to calculate RMS(root mean square) which is defined in sigma summation form:

```
for i in range(int(N-(n*periyot/delta)), N+1):
    sum = np.sqrt((1 / N) * (sum((Cl[i]**2))))
```

Then I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

Here are some information about my definitons:

```
N=40000, n=10.0, periyot=6.451290, delta=0.005  

Cl=[-21.91969   -12.452671   -7.928303  ...,  -0.0833991  -0.0579686
  -0.0823822]
```

Comment: Show the full error message please, including the information that tells *where* the error occurs.

Comment: File "/home/emre/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/fe_over_f0/fe_f0_08.py", line 70, in <module>
    

sum = np.sqrt((1 / N) * (sum((Cl[i]**2))))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Comment: It seems you are simply looking for `np.average(Cl[n1:n2]**2)`, where `n1 = int(N-(n*periyot/delta))` and `n2 = N+1`

Comment: @VBB I'll try that and inform you, thanks.

Comment: @ordinary let me know, I can post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: @VBB Unfortunately I couldn't do. I get same error. Actually I am trying to calculate RMS value.

Comment: Can you post `np.shape(Cl)` and `type(Cl)` here?

Comment: print(np.shape(Cl)) >> (40000,)
print(type(Cl))         >> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Answer (score 3):

Remove that `sum`, each element of `Cl` is a float so you can't possibly call sum on them:

```
>>> sum(2.4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

If you intend to invoke numpy's *broadcasting* to perform the power operation then you don't need to index the array.

Comment: But I need to sum all of each element of Cl. There must be an alternative way to sum them.

Comment: @ordinary You need a different logic then. You are iterating over every element and throwing away `sum` on every iteration.

Comment: Even if you do fix the error @ordinary , if you still use the built-in function `sum` you'll face another exception during the second iteration since `sum` will be rebinded to a float. Use a different name for you summation i.e `my_sum`, not `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you overwrite `sum` function with `sum` variable. Try something like this:

```
my_sum = 0
for i in range(int(N-(n*periyot/delta)), N+1):
    my_sum += np.sqrt((1 / N) * (sum((Cl[i]**2))))
```

Comment: this is the other issue, `sum(numpy.float64)` is the first.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code like you said:
for i in range(int(N-(n*periyot/delta)), N+1):
   
   rms_Cl_sum = 0
   
   rms_Cl_sum += np.sqrt((1 / N) * (sum((Cl[i]**2))))

But unfortunately I get same error. 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1):

Replicating your calculation, a bit simplified:

```
In [1]: Cl = np.array([-21.91969  , -12.452671 ,  -7.928303 ,  -0.0833991,-0.0579686,-0.0823822])
```

To calculate a sum in a loop, initial a value, and add to it at each iteration:

```
In [2]: res = 0
In [3]: for i in range(len(Cl)):
   ...:    res += np.sqrt((1/3)*Cl[i]**2)
   ...:    
In [4]: res
Out[4]: 24.551481812296061
```

Letting `numpy` calculate everything (slightly different)

```
In [5]: np.sqrt((1/3)*Cl**2).sum()
Out[5]: 24.551481812296064
```

Your range is a little more complicated, but I think that can be accommodated with:

```
s, e = int(N-(n*periyot/delta)), N+1  # start, end of range

for i in range(s, e): ....
```

or

```
np.sqrt((1/N) * Cl[s:e]**2).sum()
```

But I wonder why you started with that `sum((Cl[i]**2)))`.  Where you hoping to square a range of `Cl` values and then sum them?  And repeat that for multiple ranges?

=============

There's a `np.sum` and a Python `sum`.  Python `sum` works nicely with a list of numbers, such as those generated by a list comprehension:

```
In [6]: [np.sqrt((1/3)*Cl[i]**2) for i in range(len(Cl))]
Out[6]: 
[12.655338922053147,
 7.1895529539798462,
 4.5774078712669173,
 0.048150492835172518,
 0.03346818681454574,
 0.047563385346433583]

In [7]: sum([np.sqrt((1/3)*Cl[i]**2) for i in range(len(Cl))])
Out[7]: 24.551481812296061
```

The errors that result from trying to apply `sum` to a single value:

```
In [9]: sum(Cl[0])
....
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
In [10]: sum(12.234)
...
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

In [11]: sum(Cl[:3])     # sum of several items
Out[11]: -42.300663999999998
```

==========

```
 RMS = ( (1 / N ) * (Cl[1]^2 + Cl[2]^2 + Cl[3]^2 + ... Cl[N]^2) ) ^0.5
```

is expressed, for lists as:

```
 rms = (1/n) * math.sqrt(sum([Cl[1]**2, Cl[2]**2, ....]))
 rms = (1/n) * math.sqrt(sum([Cl[i]**2 for i in range(len(Cl))]))
 rms = (1/n) * math.sqrt(sum([c**2 for c in Cl]))   # iterate on Cl directly
 rms = (1/n) * np.sqrt(np.sum(Cl**2))     # for array Cl
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I want to simply calculate RMS. RMS = ( (1 / N ) * (Cl[1]^2 + Cl[2]^2 + Cl[3]^2 + ... Cl[N]^2) ) ^0.5 

I think sum() must work for all numbers. I mean Python must have this kind of thing. I feel very disappointed sum does not work for my numbers ( which is like -12.452671)

Comment: I added an example of using the Python `sum` function with a list comprehension.  Your error was the result of trying to apply `sum` to a single number, as opposed to a list or array.  `Cl[i]` is a single value, not a range of values.